# Learing of if and else

Tags: javascript

I have these two uls, when you click on them they change color to red, but when you click on them again they should change to the color blue. What am I doing wrong with the If and Else statement?

*It seems logical to me that if it is true, then switch to red otherwise be blue. Can you help me understand?*

```js
const ul = document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(ul);

const li1 = document.createElement('li');
const li2 = document.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li1);
ul.appendChild(li2);

function colors(evt) {
  if(true) {
  evt.target.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
  evt.target.style.color = "blue";
  };
};
ul.addEventListener('click', colors, false);
```

Comment: At what point do you expect `if(true) {` to be `false`?

Comment: `that if it is true` ..think about it...if **what** is true? with `if(true)` you didn't tell it what to compare true against, so it just becomes "if true is true", which of course is always true! You need to make it compare specifically against the current colour. You don't need `true` in there specifically, just something like `if(evt.target.style.color == 'blue')` - if the _result of that expression_ is true, then the program will enter the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if(true) is not the criteria you shall use here

```js
const ul = document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(ul);

const li1 = document.createElement('li');
const li2 = document.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li1);
ul.appendChild(li2);

function colors(evt) {
  if(evt.target.style.color === 'blue') {
  evt.target.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
  evt.target.style.color = "blue";
  };
};
ul.addEventListener('click', colors, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is fixed function:

```
function colors(evt) {
  if(evt.target.style.color == 'blue') { //this condition allows you to check the current color and change it to the opposite one. 
  evt.target.style.color = 'red';
  } else {
  evt.target.style.color = "blue";
  };
};
```